# getStream laravel integration FeedConfigException

Tags: laravel-5.5, getstream-io, php-7.0

I am trying to get getStream for laravel integrated. I have followed all the steps as mentioned in the below link. 
[getstream Laravel Integration tutorail](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-social-network-laravel-stream-easy/)

Thought the tutorial is good i am having difficultly in getting the response for feed working. When i access the feed url, below error is displayed

```
"{"detail":"timeline feed group does not exists","status_code":400,"code":6,"exception":"FeedConfigException","duration":"0.55ms"}"
```

In getStream dashboard, the log says

> The request was malformed or invalid.

[image]

Any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the error message returned from the APIs, it looks like you are trying to read a timeline feed (timeline:3) but that group is not defined on your application.

You can fix this by creating a new feed group called "timeline" on Stream's Dashboard. When you do that, make sure that you add it to the same application that you are using on Laravel.

Comment: Thanks @Tommaso Barbugli I was able to get it working. I created a new feed called timeline and it worked. Thanks for your help.